# Show that the alternating group $A_{n}$ is nonabelian for $n\geq 4$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

How would I show this? Do I use induction? I am not sure how to even begin with induction, and so I have no work to show.

Comment: Exhibit element which do not commute.

Comment: Can you give particular elements that don't commute?

Comment: Take for example A_4: can you name two elements of that group?

Comment: You are overthinking the issue.  Nonabelian amounts to the existence of a pair of noncommuting elements.  Note that for $m\le n$ one has $A_m \subseteq A_n$, at least up to isomorphism.

Comment: @hardmath I see what you mean now. That definitely simplifies a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't even need induction. If $k \leq n$, then $A_k$ is a subgroup of $A_n$, so it suffices to treat the case $k=4$.

We have $(1,2,3)\cdot(2,3,4)=(1,2)(3,4)$, but $(2,3,4)\cdot (1,2,3)= (1,3)(2,4)$, so $A_4$ is not abelian.

Comment: I was actually thinking only the case $n=4$ needs to be shown... Is that what you mean? Otherwise, you're right, induction is definitely not needed!

Comment: @numericalorange that is what I mean.

Comment: Thank you for your time and coming up with a counterexample that is easy to understand!